# Executing Multiple MSSQL Queries with PHP at once

Tags: php, sql-server

I am having trouble with executing numerous ms_sql queries at once in PHP:

Below is a simplified version of what I am trying to do:

```
$updatesql = "UPDATE Pricing SET Price = '".$_POST['price1']."' WHERE PriceID = 1 ";
$updatesql = "UPDATE Pricing SET Price = '".$_POST['price2']."' WHERE PriceID = 2 ";
$updatesql = "UPDATE Pricing SET Price = '".$_POST['price3']."' WHERE PriceID = 3 ";
$updatesql = "UPDATE Pricing SET Price = '".$_POST['price4']."' WHERE PriceID = 4 ";
$updatesql = "UPDATE Pricing SET Price = '".$_POST['price5']."' WHERE PriceID = 5 ";
$updatesql = "UPDATE Pricing SET Price = '".$_POST['price6']."' WHERE PriceID = 6 ";
$updatesql = "UPDATE Pricing SET Price = '".$_POST['price7']."' WHERE PriceID = 7 ";
$updatesql = "UPDATE Pricing SET Price = '".$_POST['price8']."' WHERE PriceID = 8 ";

$executesql = mssql_query($updatesql);
```

When I go through them one by one they all work, however when I try to execute them all at once, only the **LAST** query seems to get executed.

Is what I'm trying to do possible? Any pointers where Im going wrong? Sorry fairly new to PHP.

Comment: You are overwriting each query by the next one.

Comment: Also add `;` inside each query at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$updatesql = "UPDATE Pricing SET Price = '".$_POST['price1']."' WHERE PriceID = 1 ;";
$updatesql.= "UPDATE Pricing SET Price = '".$_POST['price2']."' WHERE PriceID = 2 ;";
$updatesql.= "UPDATE Pricing SET Price = '".$_POST['price3']."' WHERE PriceID = 3 ;";
$updatesql.= "UPDATE Pricing SET Price = '".$_POST['price4']."' WHERE PriceID = 4 ;";
$updatesql.= "UPDATE Pricing SET Price = '".$_POST['price5']."' WHERE PriceID = 5 ;";
$updatesql.= "UPDATE Pricing SET Price = '".$_POST['price6']."' WHERE PriceID = 6 ;";
$updatesql.= "UPDATE Pricing SET Price = '".$_POST['price7']."' WHERE PriceID = 7 ;";
$updatesql.= "UPDATE Pricing SET Price = '".$_POST['price8']."' WHERE PriceID = 8 ;";

$executesql = mssql_query($updatesql);
```

Answer (score 2):

Thats because your over writing the query string each time. Try the following:

```
    $updatesql = '';
    for ($i = 1; $i < 9; $i++) {
        $updatesql .= "UPDATE Pricing SET Price = '".$_POST['price' + $i]."' WHERE PriceID = {$i}; ";
    }
    $executesql = mssql_query($updatesql);
```

Comment: That would not execute the queries in once. Also, that would only work if the queries are always incremented like that

Answer (score 2):

You are overwriting your own query with the new one, so at last only the last query that you have created will be in that variable only.

So you cannot able to execute that all, to execute all you have to choose either looping or ; method with mysql.

Even though you can write mysql_query before the queries so all the query will be updated.

```
$updatesql = mssql_query("UPDATE Pricing SET Price = '".$_POST['price1']."' WHERE PriceID = 1 ");
$updatesql = mssql_query"UPDATE Pricing SET Price = '".$_POST['price2']."' WHERE PriceID = 2 ");
$updatesql = mssql_query"UPDATE Pricing SET Price = '".$_POST['price3']."' WHERE PriceID = 3 ");
$updatesql = mssql_query"UPDATE Pricing SET Price = '".$_POST['price4']."' WHERE PriceID = 4 ");
$updatesql = mssql_query"UPDATE Pricing SET Price = '".$_POST['price5']."' WHERE PriceID = 5 ");
$updatesql = mssql_query"UPDATE Pricing SET Price = '".$_POST['price6']."' WHERE PriceID = 6 ");
$updatesql = mssql_query"UPDATE Pricing SET Price = '".$_POST['price7']."' WHERE PriceID = 7 ");
$updatesql = mssql_query"UPDATE Pricing SET Price = '".$_POST['price8']."' WHERE PriceID = 8 ");
```

// $executesql = mssql_query($updatesql);

There are lot of ways to execute queries in a single statement.